# VueJS: Failed to load resource

Tags: html, css, vuejs2

I'm using VueJS. In `index.html` I put a link with my css file so I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>my-project</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/assets/sass/materialize.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I have an error saying this file

Why this occur? I sure this file is in that folder

[image]

Comment: Try using `href="assets/sass/materialize.css"`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with vue, but rather the server context it is running in.

I suspect you're likely using webpack to build and serve the content. The error may be related to the setup in webpack, you will need to provide the details of that to get help.